# How many elements are the same in two lists, which have duplicate elements

Tags: haskell

I try to find the number of elements that are the same in two lists. **There are duplicate elements in two lists**.

What I want:

```
-- (because there are two 's' in both lists )
duplicateEle "sssf" "ssah" = 2

-- (because there are two 'a' and one 's' in both lists, intotal 3 common elements)
duplicateEle "aass" "aaas" = 3

-- (because there are two 'a' and two 's' in both lists, intotal 4 common elements)
duplicateEle "ssaa" "ssaa" = 4
```

My strategy is check each element in List1 to see if it is the element in List2.

- if each element of the List1 is the element of the List2.
- If true, **count 1** and **delete** (Data.List) the corresponding element in the second list.

For example,

input "dddd" "ssdd" output 2 because there are two `d` in both lists.

First I check if the 1st element in List1 which is `d` is an element in List2, the result is True, so I delete only one d in List2, count +1, now count is 1.

Then I check if the 2nd element in List1 which is `d` is an element in List2, the result is also True, so, I delete one d in List2,count +1, now count is 2.

Because there is not any `d` left in List2, so, the count will stay at 2.

My code is: (wrong)

```
import Data.List

duplicateEleCount :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
duplicateEleCount (x:xs) ys = 
    let count = if x `elem` ys then do 1 (delete x ys) else 0
    in count + duplicateEleCount xs ys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to find the number of common elements between two lists which have repeated items, you can simply do this:

```
f x y = length $ nub $ intersect x y
```

`intersect` will find the common elements (with repetition*), and `nub` will get the distinct values from that list.

Note: `intersect` will only include repetition from the first argument i.e. `intersect "ss" "s"`  will return "ss" but `intersect "s" "ss"` will return just "s".

EDIT: Based on the clarification, we can use `foldl` to get the desired outcome like so:

```
dup x y = fst $ foldl (\acc z -> if z `elem` (snd acc) then ((1 + fst acc), delete z (snd acc)) else acc) (0,y) x
```

This applies the strategy outlined in the question - if the element is found in current value of second list, increase the count and modify the second list, else do nothing.

Comment: Thanks shree.pat18, your solution is awesome.  But, would you mind pointing out where I was wrong? and how to correct it? Because I think my solution is feasible and intuitive. I hope to know how to do it correctly. Thanks again.

Comment: Your strategy is generally OK, but the use of `do` is syntactically incorrect. Further, the delete function only removes the first instance in the list, so if you had the same character repeated in both lists, you would still end up double counting

Comment: Yeah, I realized the `do` part, because the type of y and z should be the same in " if x then y else z ". But how can I do it if I want two operations, is there any other statements?  Regarding the `list` part, since I delete the element in the 2nd list, so there no need to double counting, because the element will be doubled counting has been deleted. I'm not sure about the "double counting" you mentioned.

Comment: `delete 'a' "abca"` returns "bca" and not "bc", so if your first list is "aab", even after calling delete for the first instance of 'a', you still have another 'a' in the second list that will match the second 'a' from your first string.

Comment: ```Prelude Data.List> length $ nub $ intersect "aaaa" "ssaa"
``` Hi shree, I found a bug, when the input is `aaaa` `ssaa` the output should be 2 rather than `1`. So, I think there is something wrong.

Comment: Why? A is the only item common to both strings, so it should show 1 common element

Comment: I agree with the `delete` function, and that's the answer I want. Let me clear my question.  input `"dddd" "ssdd"` output `2` because there are two `d` in both lists.  my strategy is check each element in List1 to see if it is the element in List2. in this case, first I check if the first in List1 which is `d` is an element in List2, the result is True, so I delete only `one` `d` in List2, `count +1, now count is 1`.  Then I check if the 2nd element in List1 which is `d` is an element in List2, the result is also True, so, I delete `one` `d` in List2,`count +1, now count is 2`.

Comment: I understand what you said, but it's not what I seek. In this case `input "dddd" "ssdd" output 2 ` is correct. `input "ssaa" "ssaa" output 4`is correct it's kind of greedy match (I'm not sure about the terminology) . What I want is to find the most elements, NOT distinguished elements.

Comment: OK, can you please edit your question to clarify this?

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote is not so Haskelly. Since it's strings, we can sort them, then group:

```
import Data.List

-- group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]   -- Defined in `Data.List'

dupreps :: String -> String -> Int
dupreps a b = r
  where
     x = group $ sort a
     y = group $ sort b
```

Now we have them both ordered and grouped, we can just advance along the two lists in an obvious way,

```
     r = merge'n'count x y 0

     merge'n'count    _      []      cnt = cnt
     merge'n'count   []      _       cnt = cnt
     merge'n'count   (g:gs)  (f:fs)  cnt 
       | head g == head f  
         =  merge'n'count  gs   fs  (cnt + min (length g) (length f))
       | head g <  head f  
         =  merge'n'count  gs (f:fs) cnt
       | head g >  head f  
         =  merge'n'count (g:gs) fs  cnt
```

So that we have e.g.

```
> dupreps "aab" "abbc"
2

> dupreps "aab" "aabbc"
3

> dupreps "aabccc" "bbc"
2
```

The groups `g` and `f` in `merge'n'count` are always non-empty by construction, so using `head` is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is what you intended to write?

```
import Data.List

duplicateEleCount :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
duplicateEleCount (x:xs) ys = 
    let (count, ys') = if x `elem` ys then (1, delete x ys) else (0, ys)
    in count + duplicateEleCount xs ys'
duplicateEleCount [] _ = 0
```

You can't use `do` like you were trying to do. Remember that all variables in Haskell are immutable, so `delete` doesn't change the original list, it returns a new one that we will have to pass along to the recursive call.

A note on performance: this function is `O(n*m)`, since we have to traverse the whole second list for every element in the first list. We can sort the lists first and perform something similar to the merge operation from merge sort to bring it down to `O(n*log(n) + m*log(m)))`.

On another note, because of haskell's laziness, we can split the function up to one like this, without losing any performance and gaining flexibility:

```
import Data.List

duplicateElems :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
duplicateElems (x:xs) ys = 
    if x `elem` ys
      then x : duplicateElems xs (delete x ys)
      else duplicateElems xs ys
duplicateElems [] _ = []
 
duplicateEleCount xs ys = length $ duplicateElems xs ys
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hjulle :) now I know where I'm wrong and how to improve it. But, when I run the two solutions, (Both two have the same exception)it said `Non-exhaustive patterns`    `*Main> duplicateEleCount "ssaa" "ssaa"
*** Exception: hsmodule.hs:(72,1)-(74,39): Non-exhaustive patterns in function duplicateEleCount`. I'm confused, because it's a if .. then.. else .  So, it must cover all the patterns. It's like split the whole into two parts, if...then is part one, else is part two. Would you mind explaining  this?

Comment: Oh, right. I missed that. You don't have any case for what should happen with an empty list and I copied that mistake into my answer. The problem is the `(x:xs)` pattern and no `[]` pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are on the right direction. But in the first code, the base case should be `duplicateEleCount [] _ = 0` rather than `[]`, cause it's `[Char] -> [Char] -> Int`, But it still could not work. error:`error:
    Variable not in scope: duplicateEleCount :: [Char] -> [Char] -> t` . And the second code could not work after add base case, either.

Comment: What's wrong with the second code? I'm confused why it says "Variable not in scope", since the variable is clearly defined. Are you running it in ghci or in a file?

Comment: Thanks Hjulle, you are right, the seconde code is correct. I run is in a file.